# Relationship between assignment operator and user-defined constructor

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

```
#include <iostream>

class A{
};

class B: public A{
public:
    B(A&& inA){
        std::cout<<"constructor"<<std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    B whatever{A{}};
    whatever=A{};
}
```

This outputs

```
constructor
constructor
```

at least with C++14 standard and GCC. How is it defined that assignment operator can result in call to constructor instead of `operator=`? Is there a name for this property of assignment operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you meet all the [conditions for generating a move-assignment operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15590877/1621391). The *move-assignment operator* the compiler synthesizes for you is in the form of:

```
B& operator=(B&&) = default;
```

Recall that temporaries can be bound to *`const` lvalue references* and *rvalue references*. By [Implicit Conversion Sequences](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.best.ics), your temporary `A{}` is converted to a temporary `B` which is used to make the move assignment. You may disable this with `explicit` constructors.

Comment: "your temporary A{} is converted to a temporary B" - can you cite the draft? I am only able to find mention of derived-to-base conversion in the page you linked.

Comment: @EuriPinhollow, this has nothing to do with "derived-to-base (`B->A`)" conversion, and there is no such context in OP's snippet.... OP's code has a [*Converting Constructor*](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.conv#ctor-1)[class.conv.ctor] that takes an rvalue to an object of `A`, namely: `B(A&&)`. This means any `rvalue` object of `A` can be converted to `B`. [User-defined Conversion Sequences](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.best.ics#over.ics.user)[over.ics.user] takes into account all possible methods of implicit conversion from "the Type you passed as argument" to "the Type expected"

Comment: Edit this into answer please and I am accepting it. This part is the most important one.